# emberData bulk create hasMany relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

The app I am working on has an event model like this

```
App.Event = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    ...
    tests: DS.hasMany('App.Test')
});
```

Now I have an `EventController` to create and save a new record with `this.set('content', App.Event.createRecord());` `this.get('model').save();`
Just saving the title attribute works fine, but now I also want to be able to save the hasMany-relationships (e.g. test) via a modal-dialog.
I am creating that dialog via an `{{outlet modal}}` plus according controller, similar to some answers here on stackoverflow. So I seem to be able to get the modal to work with an `ObjectController` and

```
App.TestController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['event'],
    init: function(){
        var event = this.get('controllers.event').get('content')
        this.set('content', event.get('test').createRecord());
    }
});
```

To be honest, I haven't tested the code yet full if that even works, but it seems like it is. So the template has an according form to fill in the details. Now what I would like to have is an `ArrayController` in the back and a button in the template 'Add one more' that then sort of pushes another record into the test-model and the the template automatically adds a second form via the following template code:

```
{{#each controller}}
    ...form...
{{/each}}
```

If you need to see more of my implementation check out this question I posted yesterday: 
[Create and display EmberData models on same route/resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800375/create-and-display-emberdata-models-on-same-route-resource/17800469?noredirect=1#17800469)
Hope you understand the question, if not I am happy to clarify.

Comment: I should have done the tests a bit more thoroughly. Even the single creation doesn't work fully yet. But anyway, the question still stands. Will post more if I make any significant progress.

Comment: This is an interesting question. Please post back if you find a solution.